# Take screenshot of a webpage using pagespeedsonline

Tags: screen-capture, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I would like to capture the thumbnail of a webpage using google page speed insights.

Is it possible to turn of all the other operations except screen capture to increase the responce time. right now it is taking good amount of time.

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&screenshot=true

and also what would be the cost for making the api calls ?